# Git merge only commits within branch

Tags: git

Consider this tree below. Excuse the crappy diagram, but I think you get the idea.

I have a `MASTER` branch and a `MY BRANCH`. I create a `PATCH` branch from `MASTER` and make my fixes on this branch. I then merge the fixes into *both* `MASTER` and `MY BRANCH`. When I do this, `MY BRANCH` also gets commits `C` & `D` along with it.

```
MASTER----A----B----C----D-------------MERGE
                \         \             /
                 \       PATCH----E----F
                  \                     \
             MY BRANCH----G----H-------MERGE
```

**How can I merge *only* the commits in the patch into both `MASTER` and `MY BRANCH`?**

Comment: The branch `PATCH` should start from commit `B` (the last commit common to `MASTER` and `MY BRANCH`. The `MASTER` branch is not where you depicted it but on the commit labelled `MERGE` that has `D` and `F` as parents. Similar, `MY BRANCH` is on the commit named `MERGE` that has `F` and `H` as parents.

Comment: If you don't start the patch branch from the fork point of `MASTER` and `MY BRANCH` you need to use `git cherry-pick` to achieve your goal. But `cherry-pick` defeats the purpose of the patch branch and produces hidden problems when you want to merge `MY BRANCH` back into `MASTER`. Your workflow is correct, only the patch branch should start from a different commit.

Comment: This doesn't work though. If I can only ever start my patch branches from one unique commit I won't be able to fix the issues caused later on... keep in mind, `MY BRANCH` does not get merged back into `MASTER` later on.

Comment: You still should start the patch branch from the fork point. If you don't want to merge the branches later then `cherry-pick` is a solution. Read this series of articles that explain why `cherry-pick` is not the way to go if you want to merge the branches later: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=98325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RomainValeri noted, the graph can be drawn better.  I'll borrow his variant to start, but draw what we have *before* you try to do any merging:

```
              E---F <<< patch
             /
A---B---C---D <<< master
     \
      G---H <<< my-branch
```

The name `patch` refers to existing commit `F` and the names `master` and `my-branch` refer to existing commit `H`.

The problem you have occurs because `git merge` works based on the *commit graph*, not on the *branch names*.  The names *find* commits, which is OK as far as that goes, but if you run `git merge <commit F>`, the result will include commit `F`, which will include commit `E`, which will include commit `D`, which will include commit `C`, which will include commit `B`, and so on.

That is, any successful merge of commit `F` automatically includes *every commit leading up to and including `F` itself*.

You can use `git cherry-pick` to *copy* individual commits.  Remember, a commit is a *snapshot*, a complete set of all files.  But every commit has a *parent* commit
too.<sup>1</sup>  If you compare the snapshot in commit `E` with the snapshot in its parent commit `D`, you'll see *what you changed* in commit `E`.  If you compare the snapshot in commit `F` with its parent in commit `E`, you'll see *what you changed* in commit `F`.  A cherry-pick essentially allows you to "replay" these changes elsewhere.

This leads to the recommendation that people will often make, to use cherry-pick here.  If you make a new branch named `patch2`, starting at commit `H`, and *copy* `E` and `F` to new and improved commits `E'` and `F'`, where `E'` and `F'` come after commit `H`, you get:

```
              E---F   <-- patch
             /
A---B---C---D   <-- master
     \
      G---H   <-- my-branch
           \
            E'-F'  <-- patch2
```

You can now merge the original patch into `master` and the new-and-different (supposedly improved) `patch2` branch into `my-branch`.

There is a better way!  Well, *often*, anyway.  Let's step back for a moment and ask: *Why did you write commits `E` and `F` in the first place?*

Chances are that it is to fix a bug that is in commit `A`, or commit `B`, or maybe both.  Or maybe it adds a feature that is just lacking in commit `B`.  Whatever the case, you believe that it can be applied *without* commits `C` and `D`.

What you should do now is *prove this*.  Make a new branch `patch2` but don't point it at existing commit `H`.  Start it instead at commit `B`.  Then copy `E` and `F` to your new-and-improved `E'` and `F'`, giving:

```
          E--F   <-- patch
         /
     C--D   <-- master
    /
A--B--E'-F'  <-- patch2
    \
     G--H   <-- my-branch
```

Note that all the existing commits are still there, exactly the same.  (You have not merged anything anywhere yet.)  But if `patch2` really works, we can now *throw away* the branch named `patch`, abandoning commits `E-F`:

```
          E--F   [abandoned]
         /
     C--D   <-- master
    /
A--B--E'-F'  <-- patch2
    \
     G--H   <-- my-branch
```

Now that we've done that, let's stop drawing them, and rename existing branch `patch2` to `patch`:

```
     C--D   <-- master
    /
A--B--E'-F'  <-- patch
    \
     G--H   <-- my-branch
```

The copied (cherry-picked or **rebased**) commits `E'-F'` are now in a position in which we can run `git checkout master; git merge patch` and `git checkout my-branch; git merge patch`.  When we do, we'll get two merge commits:

```
     C--D--M1   <-- master
    /     /
A--B--E'-F'  <-- patch
    \     \
     G--H--M2   <-- my-branch
```

These merges behave the way you like: they bring *only* the patch into the branch, not any other commits unrelated to the patch.

#### This leads to a general rule about making patches

If you're going to fix a bug or add a shared feature, *find the earliest commit in your graph* where the bug or feature can go.  In this case, that was just after commit `B`.  (It might be possible to put it just after commit `A`, and if so, you can do that instead.  If the bug or feature requires part of commit `B`, though, commit `B` is the furthest back you can go.)

The reason for doing this is that the resulting patch can be *cleanly* merged to *any* commit that is "downstream" of that point.  In this case, you wanted to merge the patch into commits `D`, on `master`, downstream of `B`, and into `H`, on `my-branch`, downstream of `B`.  Since `patch`, at commit `F'`, is downstream of `B`, merging `patch` into any branch will bring in commit `B`.  But commit `B` is the first place at which branch `patch` is *useful*.  Any branch whose tip *isn't* downstream of `B` *cannot use the patch at all!*  So by placing the patch itself immediately after the first place it could possibly be *used*, *every* other branch that *can* use the patch at all, can use the patch easily and cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a `rebase` or a `cherry-pick` to apply `E` and `F` manually to `MYBRANCH` or create the `PATCH` branch properly with only `E` and `F` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range to designate which commits you want on the destination branch :

```
git checkout my-branch
git cherry-pick master..patch
```

where `master..patch` means :
*everything on* `patch`
MINUS
*everything already known on* `master`

---

As a sidenote, suggestion for a better tree schema

```
              E---F <<< patch
             /     \
A---B---C---D-------I <<< master
     \
      G---H <<< my-branch
```

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you!

Comment: Result: `error: empty commit set passed`, `fatal: cherry-pick failed`

Comment: @mr-matt Did you try this *after* the "bad" merge `patch > my-branch`? If so, no wonder the cherry-pick is empty since `E` and `F` have already been applied. The solution I'm suggesting is to be applied *instead* of merging `patch` into `my-branch`. If the merge is already done, comment and we'll discuss it.